# RSS and the Mean

Tags: regression, residuals

I was just experimenting with calculating RSS with different horizontal lines and found something peculiar. Given a data frame, why is it that when I calculate Residual Sum of Squares for various horizontal lines, that the mean is actually the value that minimizes the RSS?

For example, the `mtcars` data has a weight-mpg relationship. If I plot the mean of `mpg` and calculate the RSS for it, and likewise for other values above and below the mean, I find that it is the horizontal line that has the lowest RSS. Why is this?

[image: mtcars]

[image: mtRSS]

Comment: In the first paragraph you say "I calculate Residual Sum of Squares for various values around the mean", then in the second paragraph you write "I plot the mean and calculate the RSS for it". None of it makes sense and conflicts. mean of *what*. RSS of what. get your story straight

Comment: if you need a mathematical explanation for it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554243/understanding-the-mean-minimizes-the-mean-squared-error. basically if you predict at the mean of the data, it should minimize the error or variance

Comment: @StupidWolf That actually answers my question! Thank you for that!